# Issues running oauth from php cgi/fastcgi

Tags: php, apache, oauth, fastcgi

I've come across some issues with using oauthentication as a client through a php cgi. Apparently, cgi's seem to be missing important `apache functions`. I'm using the oauth-php library, [found here](http://status.net/open-source/issues/1822). This library requires Apache Handlers for usage. Without it, it's telling me oauth_callback is required. I think it has to do with not being able to call the function `getallheaders()`. I even tried making a hotfix by implementing the function myself, but that didn't really fan out too well. My question is, I'd like to investigate if it is actually possible to run oauth as a client through a cgi, or if I need to immediately speak with my hosting provider about switching to an Apache Handler.

**I don't want to waste any time trying to find a CGI solution if it simply is just problematic and I should speak about switching to an Apache Handler.**

Thanks.

Comment: what problems did you have? you're talking about an oauth server or client?

Comment: Updated question. I'm referring to as a client.

Comment: It is possible. Just use another library.

Comment: Can you point me to a CGI-capable oauth php library.

Comment: [that](http://php.net/manual/en/book.oauth.php) should work, and [that](https://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/) but not really sure

Comment: im not able to add pecl extensions to this hosting provider unfortunately. and, the second one is the library i am using (i noted it in my question). it only allows for apache handlers.

Comment: have you looked [here](https://github.com/search?l=PHP&q=oauth+server&ref=searchresults&type=Repositories)?